# Поиск ключа в массиве по шаблону

Tags: php, массивы, регулярные-выражения

Нужно проверить `$_GET` по шаблону на наличие ключа. Ключи, которые интересуют, имеют вид `$_GET['purpose0'], $_GET['purpose1'], $_GET['purpose...N']`. Подходящей функции или способа не нашел, чтобы искало ключ `purpose` с любой цифрой после.

Comment: сделайте массив из ключей массива $_GET и проверьте регуляркой

Answer (score 1):

```
$new = preg_grep("/^purpose\d+$/", array_keys($array));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = "/^purpose\d+$/";
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) { 
    $result = preg_match($pattern, $key);
    if($result)
    {
        echo "Совпадение\n";
    }
}
```